# How do i fix this? Oracle triggers

Tags: sql, oracle11g, triggers

I am looking to create a trigger that will bring back staff id when a row is inserted.

I have this so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_trigger 
  BEFORE
  INSERT ON staff
  FOR EACH ROW 
  DECLARE 
  v_staff_id VARCHAR2(5);
  BEGIN
  SELECT staff_id from staff INTO v_staff_id FROM dual;

  END;
```

I keep getting errors like sql statment ignored and command not ended properly for this line:

```
v_staff_id VARCHAR2(5);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the new/altered data(inserted/update data) by using semi-column ':'

As you are writing trigger while inserting the data you need to use **:new.column_name**.

In the example it is **:new.staff_id**.

For complete reference please check 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm